# Java TCP/UDP Server & Client on Heroku

Tags: java, rest, heroku, tcp, udp

I'm new to Heroku, and I was thinking about building a java RESTful web service that spins up TCP/UDP servers/clients to handle streams of data based on the RESTful calls.  Aka, the RESTful calls are the triggers of TCP/UDP server creation for streaming data.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heroku can only handle traffic over HTTP. I'm not completely clear on your use case, but if you want the servers that you spin up to handle incoming UDP traffic then you won't be able to do it on Heroku.

Comment: Thanks.  My use case is to simply transfer data as fast as possible between devices, but I see Heroku doesn't support websockets either, so I guess I need to think of another solution.

Comment: Heroku now [supports](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2013/10/8/websockets-public-beta) WebSockets as a public beta.

Answer (score 0):

This answer comes long after the question was asked, but I can confirm that today you can host a UDP server on Heroku, having just built a little proof of concept Node WebRTC app.