# UDP server on Heroku

Tags: heroku, udp

I'm trying to deploy a UDP server to Heroku using the web process, but it complains that I've never bound to the port:

```
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

I looked into Heroku's documentation and I couldn't find anything mentioning UDP. I did find it mentioning that web process is the only one that allows external HTTP requests.

Is there any process type that allow me to accept UDP?

I've also seen the question below, but it's 6 years old now, so I'm posting a new one.

[Java TCP/UDP Server & Client on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040742/java-tcp-udp-server-client-on-heroku)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think answer provided [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Heroku/comments/blnjwy/heroku_rust_server/) is still correct:

> The Heroku Router only routes new requests to apps on the common runtime to ports 80 and 443. Your app can create new outbound requests on any port, but an external visitor/user cannot create new inbound requests on arbitrary ports.
> Please pay special attention to the use of the word NEW, as opposed to the TCP/UDP “established” state.